# How to make a segue to another controller via a controller that doesnot have a direct push segue in iOS?

Tags: ios, segue

Suppose I have 3 controllers namely A, B and C. A to B I have a push segue. And I have a push segue from B to C. Now if I have to make a segue directly from A to C then without going to the B controller how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: make direct segue A to C what is stoping you ?

Comment: Its not advisable to have mutiple segues between viewcontrollers. The correct appraoch is to embed all three VC's in a navigation controller. Let the navigation controller present and dismiss view controllers as required.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually push that view controller in navigationController like this

```
UINavigationController *navigation = [self navigationController];
```

after this just insert your b View in this navigationController like this

```
[navigation pushViewController:yourController animatte:yes];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can setup the view controllers as follows :

```
Navigation_Controller -> VC_A -> VC_B -> VC_C
```

You can create the view controllers using storyboards, and then give each of your view controllers as storyboard ID.

[image: Giving the VC a Storyboard ID]

Now you can navigate to your desired VC, as follows :

```
- (IBAction)goToB:(UIButton *)sender {
VCB *theVCB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"B"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:theVCB animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)goToC:(UIButton *)sender {
    VCC *theVCC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"C"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:theVCC animated:YES];   
}
```

Note : You could achieve the same result by connecting VCB and VCC using segues but that is not advisable.